# how to write onkeyup for dynamically generated rows

Tags: php

```
for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++)
{

echo "<tr>";
for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++)
    {
        for($td=1;$td<=1;$td++)
        {

            echo "<td><input type='text' name='bhk[$tr][$td]'  value='$tr' disabled></td>";

        }
        for($td=2;$td<=$cols;$td++)
        {

            echo "<td><input type='text' name='bhk[$tr][$td]'></td>";

        }

    }

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

how to write onkeyup for dynamically generated rows.i need to hide some columns using onkeyup how i achieve

Comment: _"how [do] I achieve [this]?"_ By trying something first. And yes, `keyup` is a browser (client-side) event, so you'll have to use JS event listeners

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document.body).on("onkeyup",".class", function () {
    //do you what you want here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with plain JavaScript or with jQuery:

JavaScript

```
// add this in your input tags
..<input type='text' name='bhk[$tr][$td]' onkeyup="makeItHappen(this.value)" ..>...
function makeItHappen(val) {
    // do whatever you like
}
```

jQuery

```
// add a class to your input tags
..<input type='text' name='bhk[$tr][$td]' class="make-it-happen" ..>...

// add this to your script
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.make-it-happen').keyup(function() {
         // do whatever you like
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write an `onKeyUp` event listener in JavaScript and then make that dynamically send a request to your PHP script.

Mind that there might be a slight delay.